# Как сделать раздвигающиеся контейнеры в java?

Tags: android, java

Делаю один проект, но возникла одна проблема, хочу сделать 3 контейнера, внутр которых будет информация, если на них нажать , то они раздвинутся. Подскажите, как можно реализовать?

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-tips

Comment: @gcoder, спасибо.

Comment: @gcoder, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.